# Dimensions of Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ consisting of **skew-symmetric diagonal matrices**. What is  $\mathrm{dim} \; V$?

The skew-symmetric matrix implies that the transpose of the matrix is its negative. I.e $A^\top = -A$.

Taking into account that $A$ may be a diagonal skewed matrix, how does that determine the dimension of $V$. Would $\dim V$ simply be 3...

Comment: Welcome to math.s, KhanMan. You should use mathjax to format your math, see https://www.latex4technics.com/.

Comment: Hint: try to find two different $3\times3$ skew-symmetric diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly answer the question, you need to find a basis for skew symmetric matrices. All such matrix is of the form
$$\pmatrix{0&a&b\\ -a&0&c\\-b&-c&0}$$
A basis would consist of specific such matrices for $(a=1,\,b=c=0)$, $\ (b=1,\,a=c=0)$ and $(c=1,\,a=b=0)$.

Comment: is their a generalized form for skew-symmetric DIAGONAL matrices?

Comment: Hey, KhanMan, did you not see the comment I left on your question? Can you find as many as two different skew-symmetric diagonal matrices? Look, I'll even spot you one: the zero matrix is diagonal and skew-symmetric. Now: can you find even one more?

Comment: Are you still here, KhanMan?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Got it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it is diagonal the $\dim V$ is at most $3$. Also skew-symmetry imposes that$$A^T=-A$$since $A$ is diagonal we have $A^T=A$ therefore $$A=-A$$ or $$A=0$$which means that $$\Large \dim V=0$$